# Error with Contact Form plugin on submission

Tags: craft3, plugin-contactform

I am using the Craft Contact Form plugin (https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form) and am having an issue where I get an error page on submission. The form is submitting correctly (the submission is appearing in Form Submissions from this plugin https://github.com/Rias500/craft-contact-form-extensions) but I am getting an error page.

Ideally I would like to be redirected to the same `/contact` page with the Success flash message displayed instead of the contact form

This is what I have on my `contact.twig` page template:

```
        <div class="contact-form">
          {% if craft.app.session.hasFlash('notice') %}
          <div class="notification">
    <p class="message notice">{{ craft.app.session.getFlash('notice') }}</p>
    </div>
{% elseif craft.app.session.hasFlash('error') %}
    <p class="message error">{{ craft.app.session.getFlash('error') }}</p>
{% else %}
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact-form/send">
    {{ redirectInput('contact') }}
      <div class="element">
      <label for="name">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input id="name" type="text" required name="fromName" value="{{ message.fromName ?? '' }}">
      </div>
      <div class="element">
      <label for="email">Email Address <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input id="email" type="email" required name="fromEmail" value="{{ message.fromEmail ?? '' }}">
      </div>
      <div class="element">
      <label for="phone">Telephone Number</label>
      <input id="phone" type="text" required name="message[phone]" value="{{ message.phone ?? '' }}">
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <p class="required-info text-small"><span class="required">*</span> Required Fields</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message">{{ message.message ?? '' }}</textarea>
      </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

And this is the error I get:

```
craft\web\twig\TemplateLoaderException: Unable to find the template “”. in /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/TemplateLoader.php:122
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/TemplateLoader.php(75): craft\web\twig\TemplateLoader->_resolveTemplate('')
#1 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(270): craft\web\twig\TemplateLoader->getCacheKey('')
#2 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(350): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('')
#3 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Environment.php(40): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('', NULL)
#4 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(289): craft\web\twig\Environment->loadTemplate('')
#5 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(337): Twig_Environment->render('', Array)
#6 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/rias/craft-contact-form-extensions/src/ContactFormExtensions.php(136): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('', Array)
#7 [internal function]: rias\contactformextensions\ContactFormExtensions->rias\contactformextensions\{closure}(Object(craft\contactform\events\SendEvent))
#8 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Event.php(310): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(craft\contactform\events\SendEvent))
#9 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(636): yii\base\Event::trigger('craft\\contactfo...', 'beforeSend', Object(craft\contactform\events\SendEvent))
#10 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/contact-form/src/Mailer.php(93): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeSend', Object(craft\contactform\events\SendEvent))
#11 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/contact-form/src/controllers/SendController.php(59): craft\contactform\Mailer->send(Object(craft\contactform\models\Submission))
#12 [internal function]: craft\contactform\controllers\SendController->actionIndex()
#13 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#15 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(109): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#16 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#17 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(297): yii\base\Module->runAction('contact-form/se...', Array)
#18 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(561): craft\web\Application->runAction('contact-form/se...', Array)
#19 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(281): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#20 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#21 /Users/user/Dropbox/GIANT/Potter Group Website/Site/build/public_html/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#22 {main}
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong with this so any help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect to the same page as you are sending, you can remove `{{ redirectInput('contact') }}` as [per here](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form#redirecting-after-submit).

Here though, it's the ContactFormExtensions plugin shouting at you. Do you have an email template set in there? If you enabled the 'Send confirmation' setting, you need to give it a template.